# Webdriver not able to click on a particular link on Chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, hyperlink, click, webdriver

I have been trying to click on a particular element on Chrome using webdriver for sometime now. Weird thing is that webdriver is able to recognize all the attributes of that particular element. But when I say `Element.Click();` it just passes over without clicking on that link.

I have literally used everything that Webdriver would offer, By ID, By Class, By CSS, By XPath. Still nothing

I would really appreciate if anyone would help me out on this one.

@Prashant - Sorry. This web app is just being developed and I dont think that I can share the link with you just yet.

@Dominik - This is how I have defined the Element variable

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("h4GetStarted"));   
if(element.Contains("let's start")   
    element.click();
```

and below is the HTML code of the same:

```
<div style="margin: 44px 0px 8px 4px; cursor: pointer;" class="divRow" id="h4GetStarted">  
    <h4>let's start</h4>  
    <div class="sprite-arrow-right"></div>  
</div>
```

I am trying to click on the text which says `let's start`.

Comment: can you share the html for that link?

Comment: How is `Element` defined and what is the HTML code of your Web page?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that it works as expected when you're driving the browser (not WebDriver)?

This may not help in your situation (it may help others who arrive at this question for the same reason I did though!), but I encountered a similar problem with an unclickable checkbox - it worked with FirefoxDriver but not with ChromeDriver (I'm using Java by the way). It turns out that the ChromeDriver clicks on the middle of elements, and my checkbox wasn't clickable there.

The [ChromeDriver troubleshooting page](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/wiki/TroubleshootingAndSupport) has some useful information on resolving `Element is not clickable` errors which describes this behaviour.

I ended up solving it by using the [Advanced user interactions API](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions) which offers the ability to move the mouse to an element with an offset. Interestingly, I didn't actually have to specify an offset, as the `moveToElement()` method must select the top-left of the element (I haven't confirmed this).

So instead of

```
termsCheckbox.click();
```

I used

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(termsCheckbox).click().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your driver

driver.manage().window().maximize();

I just had an issue chrome not finding elements and clicking due to browser not being full size, and throwing the element off.